# Debug tt templates in VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, templates, subsonic3, t4

Is there a way to debug tt files? I have installed SubSonic3 and all the templates do their job except the StoredProcedures.tt. It remains empty after 'Run Custom Tool'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this article](http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-debugging-code-generation-files/) that will explain the use of both:

- JIT debugger (by placing `Debugger.Break()` in your template code) and
- Manually attaching to Visual Studio process with the second instance of Visual Studio

The second one is useful to users of systems after Windows XP:

- Vista
- 7
- Server 2008
- Server 2008 R2
- ...

Answer (score 4):

Here is an easy method.

Add lines like this one to your T4 code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is a debug message.");
```

Download and run [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from Sysinternals. Your debug messages will appear in the output window.

(Behind the scenes, these calls use win32 OutputDebugString().)

Answer (score 2):

Start your template with:

<#@ template debug="true" ...

and add:

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

to your template code to break into the compiled generator class.

Comment: This craches Visual Studio. At least it crashes mine. I suppose because there are no debuggers attached to Visual Studio process. I've found this on the net: "Note, if you are using Windows Vista or 2008 Server, this technique (using Debugger.Break()) can hang Visual Studio". http://www.olegsych.com/2008/09/t4-tutorial-debugging-code-generation-files/

Comment: I'm using VS2010 Beta 2. It doesn't crash.

Check the video here: http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/VSIPMarketing/VSX206-Code-Generation-with-T4/ @ 25:45 for a demo.